# According to the Qur'an, if one commits a sin, are they supposed to tell their future spouse?

Tags: quran, nikah, husband-wife

According to the Qur'an, if one commits a sin, such as a sexual act but not actual intercourse, are they supposed to tell their future spouse?

For example, this might be as a result of not knowing right or wrong before puberty and repented and feel ashamed.

Answer (score 1):

A *sin* performed by a child is not recorded.

> رفع القلم عن ثلاثة عن النايم حتى يستيقظ **وعن الصبي حتى يحتلم** وعن
>   المجنون حتى يعقل
>
> The pen has been lifted from three: a sleeper till he awakes, **a boy
>   till he reaches puberty**, and a lunatic till he comes to reason.
>
> <sub>[Sunan Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/53)</sub>

There is no need to tell the spouse, there is no evidence to suggest that a person must divulge their sins to their spouses, instead the instruction given is to [conceal it](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/99).

Comment: Salam i am aware of this is there anything in the quran also?

Comment: It is in the Qur'an also under [Muhammad 47:33](https://quran.com/47/33), so the hadiths in the answer apply.